# Using Iff and Sum SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, expression

I'm struggling with my expression  I'm trying to remove any values of the `WebSoldPriceForFmvRatio` and `LastFMV` that would have the `isPriorMonthAppraised` value of zero. I've attempted several attempts at using a combination of iif and sum statements but they all return with errors. Am I using the IFF statement correctly or do I need to use another conditional?
Code:

```
   =Code.Divide(SUM(
                   IIF(
                       Fields!isPriorMonthAppraised.Value=0
                      ,Fields!WebSoldPriceForFmvRatio.Value,0))
               , SUM(
                   IIF(Fields!isPriorMonthAppraised.Value=0
               ,Fields!LastFMV.Value,0)))
```

Comment: Can you paste the actual code sample here, please. There is no "IFF" statement. You must mean "IIF".

Comment: And what does "value has been not issued" mean in this context?

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw my explanation is poor I'm trying to remove any values of the `LastFMV` that would have the `isPriorMonthAppraised` value of zero.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Returns this error: `Error 2 [rsFieldReference] The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox39’ refers to the field ‘WebSoldPriceForFmvRatio’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `WebSoldPriceForFmvRatio` is not in the **same dataset** as your **table/Matrix's dataset**.

   If you need to access it from a different dataset you would need to either use **aggrgate function** or **Lookup function** or **redesign datasets**.
2. Also remember Field Names are **case sensitive**. It must match the field name under the dataset.

   `WebSoldPriceForFmvRatio` is different from `WebSoldPriceForFmvRatiO` or `WEBSoldPriceForFMVRatio`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct spelling is "IIF", not "IFF", so maybe start there.

Additionally, are you expecting 0 (as in a numeric 0), or do you need to test for NULL values?  If you need to test for NULL, use the IsNothing() function.

Comment: it's testing for a numeric 0.